# What did I wrong here [Write to file in new line]?

Tags: python, file

I want to make a simple function that writes two words to a file each on a new line.
But if I run this code it only writes "tist - tost" to the file.

Code:

```
def write_words(word1, word2):
    w = open("output.txt", "w")
    w.write(word1 + " - " + word2 + '\n')
    w.close()

write_words("test", "tast")
write_words("tist", "tost")
```

Output:

```
tist - tost
```

How can I write the two phrases to the file?

Comment: If @Kasramvd's answer was helpful for you please consider accepting it. This greatly helps the community :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to open your file in append mode, also as a more pythonic way for opening a file you can use [*`with` statement*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) which close the file at the end of block :

```
def write_words(word1, word2):
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f :
        f.write(word1 + " - " + word2 + '\n')
```